# Excel Macro Range Error when extracting columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to extract set columns from a spreadsheet that is generated each day. I am using a macro to do this, which I intend to keep on a spreadsheet, copy in the data to this sheet each day and then export the results. The macro is the following:

```
Public Sub extractCol()

Set Range1 = Range("O,P,Q,Y,AA,BT,BU")
Range1.Copy
Set newbook = Workbooks.Add
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

I get an error saying:

> run time error 1004 method range of object _global failed .

It's something about the `Set Range1 ...` line; I haven't added any ranges to the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be a little more explicit with your columns, try this ...

```
Set Range1 = Range("O:O,P:P,Q:Q,Y:Y,AA:AA,BT:BT,BU:BU")
```

... this could also be ...

```
Set Range1 = Range("O:Q,Y:Y,AA:AA,BT:BU")
```